# Changing variable values from a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have to make a todo app. Create and delete functions are done but I need to create an edit function, the same with the delete function, taking a variable by number and edit it. I'm a newbie in this field. Thank you.

```
putTodo :: (Int, String) -> IO ()
putTodo (n, todo) = putStrLn (show n ++ ": " ++ todo)

prompt :: [String] -> IO ()
prompt todos = do
    putStrLn "The list has:"
    mapM_ putTodo (zip [0..] todos)
    putStrLn " "
    command <- getLine
    getCommand command todos

getCommand :: String -> [String] -> IO ()
getCommand ('+':' ':todo) todos = prompt (todo:todos)
getCommand ('-':' ':num) todos = 
    case delete (read num) todos of
        Nothing -> do
            putStrLn "That number isn't correct."
            prompt todos
        Just todos' -> prompt todos'
getCommand "exit"      todos = return ()
getCommand command  todos = do
    putStrLn ("Invalid: '" ++ command ++ "'")
    prompt todos

delete :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
delete 0 (_:as) = Just as
delete n (a:as) = do
    let x = n - 1
    y <- x `seq` delete x as
    return (a:y)
delete _ [] = Nothing

main = do
```

Comment: I'm not sure why your `delete` returns `Maybe [a]`. You probably should at least make type aliases for your types so that it's more clear what they represent

Comment: What exactly is the question? If it's that you want the "edit" function written for you - that's not how SO works, but if you share your attempts and explain how they're not working, we will help. Also it looks like you've cut off your script at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what your `edit` function needs to do is take another argument that will change the edited item:

```
edit :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
edit 0 f (a:as) = Just (f a : as)
edit n (a:as) = do
    let x = n - 1
    y <- x `seq` edit x f as
    return (a:y)
edit _ [] = Nothing
```